# How to find filenames from ls in a file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, grep, find, ls

I am trying to find if files in a directory, output of ls, exists in a file.  So I have a file called test.txt inside this file I have few filenames like, V1.txt,v2.txt, v3.txt.
Now when I do ls I find list of files in the directory, I want to search if any of these files are on my test.txt file. 
Example:

Comment: It's not the least bit clear what you are asking.  Are you trying to write a bash script, or in some language like python or C?  Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: I am looking for unix command.  When I do an ls, lets say I get these files: V1.txt, V2.txt, V3.txt, file_list.txt.  Now the file_list.txt contains file names on that directory.  So  lets say the file_list.txt contains V1.txt V2.txt but not V3.txt.  So I need a unix  command that list out the files that are not listed on file_list.txt in this example the output will be V3.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got two tasks you want to do.

1) loop through directory listing
2) search text file for any of the names of files that were in the directory

Test Setup

```
echo "V1.txt" > file_list.txt
echo "V2.txt" >> file_list.txt
mkdir testdir
touch testdir/V1.txt
touch testdir/V2.txt
touch testdir/V3.txt
```

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `ls testdir`
do
  if grep -q $f file_list.txt; then
    echo "found $f"
  else
    echo "not found $f"
  fi
done
```